# No overload for "..." matches delegate 'EventHandler'?

Tags: c#, winforms, syntax-error

Here is a snippet of code that is used so a textbox ("TxtInput1") has only one decimal in it and only numbers in it:

```
private void TxtInput1_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

> CS0123 No overload for 'TxtInput1_TextChanged' matches delegate
>   'EventHandler'

I clicked on the error and it popped up with this:

```
form1.TxtInput1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(92, 111);
form1.TxtInput1.Name = "TxtInput1";
form1.TxtInput1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(43, 20);
form1.TxtInput1.TabIndex = 8;
form1.TxtInput1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(form1.TxtInput1_TextChanged);
```

The line `System.EventHandler(form1.TxtInput1_TextChanged);` is underlined red meaning it's wrong. Any fix for this issue?

Comment: Read the docs about TextBox.TextChanged

Comment: You could've used visual studio to generate the event handler for you. This is similar to a typographical error's questions

Answer (score 2):

The signature of your method does not match what is required to handle the TextChanged event. The second parameter for the TextChanged event is just `EventArgs`. But if you change it to that, the contents of your method won't then compile.

From the look of your method's signature, you need to be hooking this up to a KeyPress event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe your handler `TxtInput1_TextChanged` to `KeyPress` event of `TxtInput1` rather than `TextChanged`. Error is due to signature mismatch of delegates.

change to below :

```
form1.TxtInput1.KeyPress+= new System.KeyPressEventHandler(form1.TxtInput1_TextChanged);
```